sqlite3_open() and icloud drive
Is it possible and if so how? to use sqlite3_open(), to open an existing file on my iCloud drive?
I have tried:-
  var db: OpaquePointer?
    let dbURL = "http://icloud.com/iclouddrive/...."
    if sqlite3_open(dbURL, &db) ==  SQLITE_OK { 
        ......

Which, of course, did not work

sqlite3_open() only works with a file path, not a URL. And you definitely do not want to try to open a file that can be updated by other processes.

I am trying to code an app that I can use across all my devices that will store my daily Blood Glucose levels and eventually compare that to a food diary. So what should I use?

You have 3 options. 1) Use SwiftData, 2) Use Core Data, 3) Write your own code that uses CloudKit to sync data which is backed locally by the SQLite database.

Which is the easiest?

Ignoring learning curves, the 3 options I listed are essentially listed easiest to hardest. But there's also the fact that SwiftData requires iOS 17/macOS 14 or later so if you need to support older versions, it rules out that option.

OK, Thank you I will have a go at swiftdata and see how I get on.
